# How do I link to specific tabs from another page?

Tags: javascript, function, tabs

I've set up my first tab to open by default on page load, but on some occasions, I want display the second or third tab when linked to another page. How can I accomplish this?

I tried linking to the tab's ID, but the defaultOpen tab is the one that remains visible. I was thinking I could call the `openTab()` function, passing the ID of the tab I wanted to view, but I don't know how to code that when going to another page. Any guidance you can offer would be much appreciated.

Here's the basic HTML tab skeleton.

```
<div class="new-tab-section">
  <div class="tabs">
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'InstallationTab')" id="defaultOpen">Installation</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'TrainingTab')">Training</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'TroubleshootingTab')">Troubleshooting</button>
  </div>
</div>
                
<div class="newsection">                
    <div id="InstallationTab"> content </div>
    <div id="TrainingTab"> content </div>
    <div id="TroubleshootingTab"> content </div>
</div>
```

Here's my Javascript.

```
function openTab(evt, tabName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you include the relevant CSS as well? It would be even easier to help you if you can modify your question to include a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I believe the issue is that the `divs` under `newsection` are all missing the `class="tabcontent"`. As a result, the `tabcontent` collection is empty and the first for loop doesn't hide the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the hash. You can add #tabID to your anchor like **page.html#TrainingTab** and look for location.hash. If location.hash is empty, I replace it with the ID of the default tab.

I also took the opportunity to rewrite your code.

First, instead of all of the javascript loops, I simply set the tab content to be display none via CSS.

And I delegated the click handler to the document instead of on a button by button basis. And pass the tabcontent id via data-attribute on the buttons.

```js
document.addEventListener("click",(e) => {
  let el = e.target;
  if(el.classList.contains("tablinks")){
      let activeContent = document.querySelector(".tabContent.active");
      if(activeContent)activeContent.classList.remove("active");
      
      let activeTab = document.querySelector(".tablinks.active");
      if(activeTab)activeTab.classList.remove("active");
      
      el.classList.add("active");
      let tabTarget = document.querySelector(el.dataset.target);
      tabTarget.classList.add("active");
  }
});

const openTarget = location.hash ? location.hash : "#InstallationTab";
const tabContent = document.querySelector(openTarget);
tabContent.classList.add("active");

const tab = document.querySelector("[data-target='" + openTarget + "']");
tab.classList.add("active");
```

```css
.tabContent{
  display:none;
}

.tabContent.active{
  display:block;
}

.tablinks.active{background:red;}
```

```html
<div class="new-tab-section">
  <div class="tabs">
    <button class="tablinks" data-target="#InstallationTab">Installation</button>
    <button class="tablinks" data-target="#TrainingTab">Training</button>
    <button class="tablinks" data-target="#TroubleshootingTab">Troubleshooting</button>
  </div>
</div>
                
<div class="newsection">                
    <div class="tabContent" id="InstallationTab">InstallationTab content </div>
    <div class="tabContent" id="TrainingTab"> TrainingTab content </div>
    <div class="tabContent" id="TroubleshootingTab"> TroubleshootingTabcontent </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @imvain2! Your code worked perfectly.

I am wondering...is there a way to jump into the tab and then down to the middle of the content? Say there's a long block of text with a subsection near the bottom I want to reach with one click.

Answer (score 0):

Each of The tabs has a button and content, you just need to change the active button and the active content:

**In page which you want to call the link:**

```
add the link : https://example.com/page-of-tabs?tab=tab-number
```

**In page of tabs:**

```
// lines to get value of tab ex: 1,2,3
const tabParam = window.location.search;
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(tabParam);
const tabNumber = urlParams.get('tab');



// if tabNumber = null, so the default tab will charge.
// if not null, so will charge the target tab by code below:
if(tabNumber != null){
//The role of document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {our code},false) is to charge our code after load page this is important!!
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
          let button = document.getElementsByClassName("classOfButtons");
          let content = document.getElementsByClassName("classOfContents");                                                
          button[indexOfDefaultButton].classList.remove("active");
          button[indexOfTargetButton].classList.add("active");
          content[indexOfDefaultContent].classList.remove("active");
          content[indexOfTargetContent].classList.add("active");
          
      }, false);
}
```

*I hope my answer helps.*